# Случайные данный из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Как из базы данных (ms sql) получить случайный столбец с данными? Учитывая что значением Id используется GUID - генерировать рандомное число и лезть в бд плохо скажется на производительности. Какой алгоритм посоветуете для запроса?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT <рандомное число>, 1` и вы же имели в виду строку, а не столбец, так? Если нет, то что-то пошло не так при проектировании таблицы.

Comment: `генерировать рандомное число и лезть в бд плохо скажется на производительности` есть такая штука - индексы. Добавьте индексацию по колонке, которая используется для выборки или сортировки, и все станет быстро и прекрасно. У вас же не 10кк записей в таблице?

Comment: @aepot то есть сделать еще один первичный ключ (значение которого будет int и  идти с 1) и использовать его в подобных целях? Если я правильно понял то тогда вопрос - как лучше его назвать?

Comment: Ну вы хотите взять рандомную запись, зачем тогда вам сортировка и еще ключ? Я просто к примеру сказал, добавить индексы на случай если нужна фильтрация или сортировка по конретной колонке, не путайте ключи и индексы. Просто `LIMIT N, 1` для начала попробуйте. EF плохо знаю, но наверное что-то типа `.Skip(n).Take(1)` должно быть.

Comment: @aepot большое спасибо за помощь